# Macbook - put my application in space without full screen mode

Tags: terminal, spaces, fullscreen

I am using Macbook Pro and I like to have different applications running in multiple spaces. When I drag my application to a new space it automatically enters in full screen mode. In my terminal, one of the command line tool that I am using requires accessing mac settings UI, and when it's in Full screen mode it can't do so. So, every time I need to run that command, I have to do these steps:

1. Exit Full screen. This makes my terminal app go to some other space and the current space is not there anymore.
2. Fire the command, which works now as I am not in Full screen mode.
3. Again drag my terminal to new space in full screen mode.

Considering the frequency of this thing, this has become a tedious repetitive task.

While this can be due to some bug in the CLI tool that I am using, I was wondering if there is any way to stay in the same space without entering into full screen mode.

Comment: I've never seen the behaviour you describe. How are you dragging to the new Space? Just grabbing the title bar & dragging hard right.. or..?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes just clicking on the app anywhere and drag it to the space...to be clear, this doesn't happen for the first space, I can fit multiple applications there but it only happens for the rest of the spaces wherein I can only fit one application in one space in full screen mode/have to share screen among applications.

Comment: I've never known a Space automatically jump into fullscreen. If you try to drag beyond your last ready-made Space it should just stop & not drag any further. How many Spaces do you have already? Does the same happen if you trigger Mission Control & drag into one of those 'mini Spaces' at the top? Does the same happen if you grab the top bar & hit the key command for your desired Space [usually Ctrl/number]

Comment: I currently have 4 spaces and everytime I drag some app(just tried it with terminal) to create a new space, it enters full screen. Everytime I try to exit full screen that app goes back to the 1st space, but I just want it to be in the newly created space.

Comment: Dragging shouldn't create a new space [unless this is a laptop thing, we only have desktops here]. You should drag to an existing Space; I think you might be triggering the first part of split-screen [which is also just a laptop thing] or just use the key command which is a whole lot faster anyway.

Comment: I actually don't get this problem. If app window is entered into full screen then new Space is created. If it's exited from full screen then it goes back to Space from which it was created and no empty Space is left behind. I wonder about general workflow as well - there are ⌘+TAB, double-click on window title bar to maximize, Zoom etc combination of which could deliver desired result with less effort.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg - I think you missed the point. OP doesn't want the window size to change, or for it to become fullscreen. Cmd/tab will not switch to a specific window, most especially if an app is spread to multiple Spaces. I still think split-screen is being partially triggered & the fix is to use the key commands not drag.

Comment: Yes, I stated that I miss the point :-). Actual objective is still elusive to me. Nevertheless, by using ⌘+TAB to navigate to desired app and without releasing ⌘ pressing down or up arrow one can display all app windows regardless of Space they are located (except Full Screen ones). Using arrow keys and enter one can easily navigate to desired window irrespective of Space.

Comment: Sorry for the lousy explanation, I think the video of what I wanted to do would have surely helped here.......anyway, found a way to fix it and posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly dragging an application and creating a new space, if I click on the plus icon on the right side, and then move the application to it or directly drag the application to that + icon, the app is not entering into full screen mode. This fixes the issue.